# How to create insertOrThrow method in room Dao?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have started migrating my SQLite code to the room. I want to know how can we create insertOrThrow (as in SQLite) method in DAO?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your DAO's method with throws SQLException (android.database.SQLException).

Hope this work for you as in my case.

```
  @Insert
  public abstract void guardaVariedades(Variedad... variedades) throws SQLException;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are having problem when insert a new row (due to conflicts when adding, ie: the value you add already existed), you can try adding one of the following attribute to **Insert** annotation:

1. ABORT: (default)to roll back the transaction on conflict
2. REPLACE: to replace the existing rows with the new rows
3. IGNORE: to keep the existing rows
   I have searched ways to throw the exception but didn't succeed, the above way solve the problem